# .NET get a local temp directory accessible by all users

Tags: .net, directory

As the title states, how can i get a temp directory acessible by all users.

`Path.GetTempPath()` returns the temp directory for the current user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%SystemRoot%\Temp");
```

Be aware though, that temp directories are a significant possible security risk, as they can be used to attack other users via corrupting shared data.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the info, I only need to create temp files then delete them immediately